# Mysql relationship between tables

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a question to now what is the best solution to make relations between tables:
I have :

- client table with id name sector_id delegation_id
- sector table with id name
- delegation table with id name sector_id

My question is that **is it a good practice to have both foreign keys in the client table or just the key of delegation_id is sufficient for indexing and searching in the client table (of course with join tables)**

to explain more
each delegation belongs to a sector.
each sector belongs to a zone
and each Client belongs to a delegation that belongs to a sector that is grouped in a geographical area

this is my Entity files : 
Class client

```
class Client {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sector", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sector;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="delegation", type="integer")
     */
    private $delegation;

}
```

Class sector

```
class Sector {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Delegation" ,mappedBy="sector")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Zone", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $zone;

}
```

class Delegation

```
class Delegation {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Sector", inversedBy="id" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $sector;

}
```

Comment: This is a very subjective question. It depends largely on the data, and how you plan to use it.

Comment: Please show us sample data and describe the logical relationships between the three tables.

Comment: to explain more
each delegation belongs to a sector.
each sector belongs to a zone
and each customer belongs to a delegation that belongs to a sector that is grouped in a geographical area

Comment: Please clarify by editing your post, not by adding comments. PS Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question -

If each `Client` belongs to a `Delegation`, the `Client` entity should have a `delegation_id` foreign key.

If each `Delegation` belongs to a `Sector`, the `Delegation` entity should have a `sector_id` foreign key.

And if each `Sector` belongs to a `Zone`, the `Sector` entity should have a `zone_id` foreign key.

You would therefore remove your `sector_id` foreign key from your `Client` entity, and use the relationship through the `Delegation` entity to find all `Client` entities within a given `Sector`, if this were ever required.

Comment: that's the answer I'm looking for to have a performance in indexing my database.
Thank you

Comment: @Funpro Please consider accepting this answer to show it helped, google 'stackexchange accept answer.